# What is the most efficient way to show lots of related data?

Tags: sql, database

I need to render a school schedule in a very detailed way [(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp5Am.png). Every Day, Hour of the day, Room, Group and Teacher are separate entities that are related one to another in a certain way.

My issue is I have to pull data to every single cell via separate query and that's how I am having over 700 queries to get week's schedule.

The question is: what is the best approach to store, manipulate and pull data for such demands?

I was thinking about making a separate 'static' table to store the actual values, not related ID's, but then I am loosing flexibility.

Comment: What about having a single table for the schedule and pull all the week's records in one query?

Comment: One query per cell. Really? O_o Isn't all that schedule data contained in the same table then?

Comment: Ok, this is a lack of knowledge. Looks like left join on couple tables solved my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my best try.

> - `id`
> - `date`
> - `room_id`
> - `group_id`
> - `teacher_id`

If you're sure that the data is very static, it might be more manageable to put teacher_9, group_9 etc. as columns in your Schedule Table. Tradeoffs are yours.

For Teacher data, you most likely want it in a different table for future changes. Imagine a Name change. Same with Group and Room.

If you're concerned about query performance, know that SQL will cache your results :).

Comment: Actually, this is pretty similar to what I've came up with. Thanks